# App working in Android but not in UWP (Video and IndicatorView not working on Xamarin Forms UWP)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have a problem regarding the `MediaElement` and the `IndicatorView`.

[image: Resources in Android]

I have this video in resources in Android to play inside the `MediaElement`.

It works perfectly fine and I don't experience problem when executing it in the Android.

But when I change the Start up Project to UWP, The video is not playing nor showing. And the `IndicatorView` does not automatically sliding.

This it the UWP Resources.

[image: UWP Resources]

This is my code.

**IndexPage.xaml**

```
<Grid>
        <MediaElement x:Name="BgVideo" Source="ms-appx:///video.mp4" ShowsPlaybackControls="False"
                      IsLooping="True" AutoPlay="True" Aspect="AspectFill"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
        </MediaElement>

        <BoxView>
            <BoxView.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint ="1,0" EndPoint = "1,1">
                    <!--<GradientStop Color ="Transparent" Offset="0"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Color ="#bdc3c7" Offset="0.9"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Color ="#2c3e50" Offset="1"></GradientStop>-->
                    <GradientStop Color ="Transparent" Offset="0"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Color ="#5D9FFF" Offset="0.48"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Color ="#6BBBFF" Offset="1.0"></GradientStop>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </BoxView.Background>
        </BoxView>

        <Grid HeightRequest="280" Margin="30,30,30,100"
              RowSpacing="40" VerticalOptions="End">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <CarouselView x:Name="cvOnBoarding" IndicatorView="LandingIndicator" IsScrollAnimated="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding OnBoardings}" HorizontalOptions="End"
                          Grid.Row="0" IsSwipeEnabled="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Spacing="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Caption}" TextColor="White" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   WidthRequest="220" HeightRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="Start" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Heading}" TextColor="White" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   WidthRequest="250" HeightRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="Start" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>

            <IndicatorView x:Name="LandingIndicator" Grid.Row="1" IndicatorsShape="Circle"
                           IndicatorColor="#B8B8B8" SelectedIndicatorColor="#E7305E" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="End">
                <Grid>
                    <Button Grid.Column="0" x:Name="btnSignup" Text="Sign Up" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="145"
                        BackgroundColor="#E7305E" TextColor="White" CornerRadius="25" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnLogin" Text="Login" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="145"
                        BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="#2E4159" CornerRadius="25" FontAttributes="Bold" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

**IndexPage.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class IndexPage : ContentPage
    {
        Timer tmrAnimator;
        public IndexPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            this.BindingContext = new IndexViewModel();
            AnimateMe();
        }

        private void AnimateMe()
        {
            tmrAnimator = new Timer(5000) { AutoReset = true, Enabled = true };

            tmrAnimator.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
            {

                if (BgVideo.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Playing)
                {
                    BgVideo.Play();
                }


                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    if (cvOnBoarding.Position == 3)
                    {
                        cvOnBoarding.Position = 0;
                    }

                    cvOnBoarding.Position += 1;
                    LandingIndicator.Position = cvOnBoarding.Position;
                    
                });
            };
        }
    }
```

The main problem is that, The Android Project is working fine, but in the UWP Project, it does not work. How can I fix this issue to work both on the project?

Comment: You are not getting an exception so either the code is not being called or the video is playing and you are not seeing the video.

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean by `not being called`? When I was debugging and tried to breakpoint the method it was hit by the debugger so I am sure, it is called.

Comment: You did not say in posting that you did the debug step.  May OPs who post skip the debugging step.  So it looks like the video is running and not getting displayed.

Comment: @jdweng  what could be the possible problem?

Comment: Have you tried place the video file in Assets folder and set build action as content?

Comment: The picture box wasn't added to the form or the picture box is behind another object

Comment: During testing, even use http uri as source, it will not play the video, it looks a bug for xamarin community tool kit.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yeah I already tried that.. seems not working too.

Comment: OK, it looks a bug, please feel free post it in Xamarin community issue box

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT on what link?

Comment: Here is [link](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues).